how to import SimpleDirectoryReader, VectorStoreIndex in vscode
from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader, VectorStoreIndex

tried running the above command in vscode Jupyter notebook
how to solve it, i have installed all the packages and libraries,still issue is not resolving
